# One of X number of colums must contain data

Tags: sharepoint

HI all,
I am creating a timesheep app and I have five colums that can contain hours worked. When the user enters a new form how do I check to see if at least one of the columns contains data. I must admit I am not a developer just a Sharepoint/Sharepoint designer hack so be nice. Thanks

Glenn Thibeault

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only bullet-proof way would be to create a SharePoint event receiver using C# (lots of examples on the web).

I'm not really sure how you could accomplish this with SPD.

If you don't want to write any C# code, that really only leaves JavaScript. It will still take development work (this is a programming site after all). You could probably take advantage of [SPUtility.js](http://sputility.codeplex.com/) (full disclosure, this is a library I maintain).

The basic steps would be:

1. Edit your NewForm.aspx and add a Content Editor web part
2. Inside the Content Editor web part, write your JavaScript:

   - Attach a new `onClick` handler to the NewForm.aspx's "OK" buttons
   - Use SPUtility's `GetValue` method to get the value of your 5 fields, validate one has a value, and display a message if invalid

Comment: Thanks Kit I will give it a try. This may solve another problem of mine also.